# Is it possible to change icons of gnome applications?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome, icons

I know this may be completely irrelevant to the functionality of the operating system, but I just finished installing debian 11 and I noticed that gnome applications use the slightly outdated icons, event though they are newer versions.

For example in my ubuntu 20.04 `gnome-calculator` is version `3.36.0` and has this icon:

[image]

While in debian 11 it is `3.38.2` and has this one

[image]

This is also valid for a few other gnome applications that I use and I would be really happy if I could switch to the icons that I like better.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: See https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Desktop_icons

Comment: perhaps the question should be `where are the icon files located?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome has *themes*; it seems you've gotten switched to a different one than you were used to. You can find the theme selection in the control center by looking for "themes".

If the original theme is not available there, you can probably still install it later on via apt, or from [Gnome LOOK](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse?cat=132&ord=latest).

The icon shown isn't hence linked with the version of your calculator application, but with the icon set.

Comment: That was very useful information. However in debian 11 searching for "themes" didn't help a lot. Turned out you need to go to `gnome-tweaks` then appearance and manage from there. Also turned out the theme I referenced is called `Yaru`, it and many more can be found at https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/